# How to add a button and functionality to blueimp gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blueimp

I'm trying to add an extra button to blueimp gallery (gotten from https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) besides the play-pause when the gallery is shown as a lightbox. The purpose of that button is to push the src of the image being displayed in the lightbox at the moment into an array, but since the gallery is filled dynamically, I haven't been able to find out how to get that data... how can I get the src of that specific element? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: you can use the onslide event to save the current slide and on click of the button you take the saved slide src

Comment: @madalinivascu so then the slide is an img tag?

Comment: its the active slide so it should have in it a image

Comment: @madalinivascu Thanks, I was able to display the src of the image on `setTitle` function, printing on an alert with this `this.slides[index].firstChild.getAttribute("src")`, however now I'm having trouble knowing what `this` object is, and how I can reference to it from the page I'm building the blueimp gallery in. If I alert what window.blueimp.Gallery is I get the function that builds the gallery, so the question would be, what does `this` mean as seen from my page point of view?

Comment: you can console.log it to se what it is, most likely a javascript object created by the plugin